# optimization problem in the spirit of the Isoperimetric problem

Tags: analysis, optimization, solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier

I consider the functional $J(y)= \int_{0}^{a}y(x)dx$ where $a$ is fixed and $v\in H^{1}(0,a)$. We have  a set of constraints

$$
K = \{ y\in H^{1}(0,a) : F(y) = \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1+y’(x)^{2}}dx - l=0\}
$$

Where $l\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is fixed. Now I would like to use Lagrange multiplier, I need to find the derivative of $J$ which is $J’(v)(h)= \int_{0}^{a} h(x)dx$ and the derivative of $F$, and here is my main difficulty :

$$
F(y+h) = \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{1 + y’(x)^{2} +2y’(x)h’(x) + h’(x)^{2}}dx - l
$$

From there, I don’t know how to purse with this square root, I would like to have your help through some hints please.

Thank you a lot

---

Thanks to Ted Shriffin, I propose the following update

First we put $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ and $f(x) = (x’)^{2}$ where $x$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

$$
L(y+h)=\int_{0}^{a}g(f(y+h))dx - l = \int_{0}^{a}g(f(y) + f’(y)(h) + o_1(h))dx - l = \int_{0}^{a}g(f(y)) + g’(f(y))(f’(y)(h) + o_1(h)) + o_2(f’(y)(h) + o_1(h))dx - l = L(y) + \int_{0}^{a}g’(f(y))(f’(y)(h))dx + \int_{0}^{a}g’(f(y))(o_1(h)) + o_2(f’(y)(h) + o_1(h))dx 
$$

It can be show that the last term is a small o (though I did not check yet). Then we have

$$
L’(y)(h) = \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+(y’(x))^{2}}}2y’(x)h’(x)dx
$$

We notice that $J’(y)(h)=\int_{0}^{a}h(x)dx$. Now this maximization problem has a solution so the Lagrange theorem provides the existence of a $\lambda$ such that at the minimizer $y$ we have

$$
J’(y)(h) + \lambda L’(y)(h) = \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y’(x))^{2}}}y’(x)h’(x) +\lambda h(x)dx = 0 
$$

From there, I think I should do an integration by part but when I tried this either with $h$ fixed or $y$ I find nothing that permits me to extract the form of $y$. Is this the good path please ?

---

Second update

Doing an integration by part for $L’(y)(h)$ we get

$$
L’(y)(h) = \int_{0}^{a} \left(\frac{y’’(x)}{\sqrt{1+y’(x)^{2}}} - \frac{y’’(x)y’(x)}{(1+y’(x)^{2})^{3/2}}\right)h(x)dx
$$

(Since $h(x)$ vanishes at the boundary)

Thus we get

$$
J’(y)(h) + \lambda L’(y)(h) = \int_{0}^{a} \left(1+ \lambda\frac{y’’(x)}{\sqrt{1+y’(x)^{2}}} - \lambda\frac{y’’(x)y’(x)}{(1+y’(x)^{2})^{3/2}}\right)h(x)dx = 0 
$$

From there, the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations allows me to get

$$
1 +\lambda\left(\frac{y’’(x)}{\sqrt{1+y’(x)^{2}}} - \ \frac{y’’(x)y’(x)}{(1+y’(x)^{2})^{3/2}}\right) = 0 
$$

Comment: I think you're writing $v$ instead of $y$ or vice-versa?

Comment: The isoperimetric problem refers to closed curves, not to graphs over an interval. The functional $F$ depends on $y$ and $y’$, and you need to differentiate with respect to $y’$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you a lot for your comment. I tried to use this and I think it is more or less this ! Let me know if something is not correct in what I have written !

Comment: You want to integrate $L'(y)(h)$ by parts to get $h$ instead of $h'$. This will then give you, ultimately, an integral of the form $\int_a^b \Phi(y,y',y'')h(x)\,dx$. At this point you apply the standard lemma of the calculus of variations to deduce that $\Phi(y,y',y'') = 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the comment ! I did not know this lemma. I  tried something as an update but the expression is not easy to manipulate (I would like to anti derivative at some point I guess) I will continue to update once I find the anti derivative.

Comment: You should end up with $$\frac d{dx}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} = \frac1\lambda.$$ Integrate without doing the derivative as you did.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for this hint ! However I do not see how you get this result ?

Comment: You should have that if you don't actually take the $x$ derivative when you integrate by parts. I think I did lose a minus sign, though.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh yes,  the notation was clear I was somewhere else sorry. This is roughly (minus sign) what I got !

Comment: @TedShifrin If you want to post an answer (just the copy of your preceding comment) in order that I can give you the bounty, it would be fair since thanks to you  I (essentially you in fact..) have solved the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard integration by parts procedure leads you to the Euler-Lagrange equation for the (constrained) extremum: If we're considering the functional
$F(y) = \int_a^b \Phi(x,y,y')\,dx$, then at a local extremum we have
$$\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y} = \frac d{dx}\left(\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y'}\right).$$
In this case, including the Lagrange multiplier, we should get the equation
$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'{}^2}}\right) = -\frac1\lambda.$$